# Trying to switch Bootstrap 4 container class media queries to go from desktop first to mobile instead of the default way - mobile first to desktop

Tags: css, mobile, responsive, desktop

Sorry for the extremely novice and beginner question, but I just can't seem to figure this out.

I want to use Bootstrap 4 container class along with the container media queries, because I very much like how BS wraps the content in the container and the responsiveness of it.

I've read a few things stating that you should really code for mobile first, but I've also seen people suggest that it really doesn't matter if you code for mobile first or desktop first.  I've been designing for desktop first so it's just easier for me right now, and the  BS container class starts with mobile first and then ends with desktop. I'd like to use their container class, with the same widths and values, but I just want to switch to desktop first (have desktop be the default one) and then  end with mobile, instead of the default way of mobile first and then ends with desktop width, like I said above.

For the life of me I just can't seem to figure out how to edit the media queries for the container class to do exactly what I said. I've switched the order, used max-width instead of min-width and I just can't seem to get it to work at all, and I can't figure out what I'm specifically doing wrong.

Here are the usual BS4 container class media queries. Can someone help me edit this so it starts with desktop first and ends with mobile?

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}
```